# Express send information to user with a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code

```
var user = function(req,res,next) {
db.findOne({ username: req.params.uid }, function (err, docs) {
//error handaling
if(err){console.log(err)}
//check if user is real
if(docs === null){
     res.end('404 user not found');
}else{
    //IMPORTANT PART res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/user.html');
    }
});
```

}

```
app.get('/user/:uid',user);
```

Don't worry about the database stuff.

I want to know how to get req.params.uid sent to the client side and how to get it from there.

Thanks so much.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by `sent` to the client side. If you just want to get it each request, you could sent it as a cookie. Check these out [`res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie) to send the cookie and [`req.cookies`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.cookies) to get it in future requests.

Comment: your question is a bit vague, are you asking how to send req.params.uid to the client? if that's the question, `req.params.uid` means it was already sent from the client

Comment: try this `return response.render('yourview', req.params.uid);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user is configured correctly every request will have a user:

```
var user = function(req,res) {
db.User.findOne({ _id: req.user._id }, function (err, docs) {
//error handaling
if(err){console.log(err)}
//check if user is real
if(docs === null){
     res.end('404 user not found');
}else{
    res.json(docs)
    }
});
```

and then your api endpoint is just `'/user/`

In your client just make a `GET` request to this endpoint (maybe using AJAX) and your response will be any user that makes that given request.

Note: You don't need to pass in `next` unless you are defining middleware.

Comment: And if that's not correct, then yes, your question is too vague. Maybe you are trying to use a server templating engine like Jade or EJS..

Comment: Thanks this helped heaps exactly what I needed

Comment: Could you than please accept it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a more complete answer based on my comment.

If you want to store a string of information about the user with each request they make, then you want to use [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

When the user first makes a request to the page, you would set the cookie via the [`res.cookie`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie). So, in your code, the final `if` statement would look something like:

```
if(docs === null) {
    res.end('404 user not found');
} else {
    res.cookie('uid', req.params.uid, { httpOnly: true });
    //IMPORTANT PART res.sendFile(__dirname + '/frontend/user.html');
}
```

Then, in the next request, and futures requests before the cookie expires, you can access it using:

```
req.cookies.uid
```

However, you need the [`cookie-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware somewhere in your app beforehand:

```
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser());
```

If you need to access the value of `uid` on the clientside, you could either use a template, or set the `httpOnly` value to `false` when setting it using `res.cookie`. Then you could access the `cookie` using [`document.cookies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Check out [this W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) for accessing cookies on the clientside.